# dma_map_single internals on arm archtecture

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, dma

I am trying to understand the DMA internals on ARM architecture, referring kernel documentation: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt.

My understanding is we allocate memory in kernel space (with DMA constraints) and pass it to the `dma_map_single()` function, this function will change the mapping attributes of memory according to the DMA needs (write combine or non-cached). Then it will return the virtual address of the device bus if the platform support IOMMU or it will return the physical address which can be directly accessed from the device.

Is it correct understanding?

Currently, I am not able to map it source code, any pointers with code snippets will be really helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not quite.

For the streaming DMA API (i.e. `dma_map_*()`/`dma_unmap_*()`), nothing is actually remapped. Only addresses from the kernel linear mapping (i.e. normal `kmalloc()` memory) are valid for streaming DMA, so since the CPU mapping is cacheable, the `dma_map_*()` operations for a non-coherent device will clean/invalidate the caches as appropriate for the extent of the buffer and rely on the CPU not accessing it until the corresponding `dma_unmap_*()`. That will then (if appropriate) invalidate the caches again, in case of any speculative fetches in the meantime, before the CPU may read any data written to memory by the device. For cache-coherent devices, none of that is needed, so it's skipped.

Since the buffer is in the linear map, the DMA address is a simple case of a `virt_to_phys()` offset, minus any device-specific offset to convert between physical memory and bus addresses in certain cases of funky hardware (e.g. Raspberry Pi 2/3 or TI Keystone 2) - see e.g. [the ARM implementation of `dma_map_page()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.c?v=4.7#L125) (of which [`dma_map_single()` is merely a special case](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/dma-mapping.h?v=4.7#L123)). Where an IOMMU is involved, there is the additional step of creating an IOVA mapping for that physical address, and returning that IOVA instead of the underlying bus address.

Note that for the *coherent* DMA API (i.e. `dma_alloc_coherent()`), when a device is not cache-coherent itself, we *do* create a separate non-cacheable mapping of the allocated pages in the vmalloc area, then use that non-cacheable alias for all CPU accesses to that buffer (after some initial cache maintenance to clean the linear map alias), since unlike streaming DMA, both the CPU and the device are allowed to access a coherent buffer at any time.

Comment: thank you, this clarifies a lot. I checked the code, pfn_to_bus convert the pfn to a physical address as you said, but I can not see the bus offset being applied. #define __pfn_to_bus(x) __pfn_to_phys(x). Am I missing something?

Comment: @shunty You want [`pfn_to_dma()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/dma-mapping.h?v4.7#L54).

Comment: 'pfn -= dev->dma_pfn_offset;' this dma_pfn_offset is specific to the device? Is it gets intialized during device configuratoin?

Comment: Indeed. In most cases, it does represent a general bus offset rather than a device-specific one, but Linux only handles things on a per-device basis. See `of_dma_configure()` for how it gets configured from the "dma-ranges" DT property.

Comment: And while using the streaming API, CPU can not use the memory until it is unmapped? Coherency(invalidating and flushing cache) should be taken care by the device driver?

Comment: @Notlikethat, "Where an IOMMU is involved, there is the additional step of creating an IOVA mapping for that physical address, and returning that IOVA instead of the underlying bus address." but isn't the DMA address (bus address) is returned when IOMMU is involved instead of IOVA  or IOVA's are nothing but the DMA addresses ? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.c#L1382